# Sinch - Android , Instant Message History returns in full when user uninstall and install the app

Tags: android, sinch

I am using the sinch service to build a chat app in android and I realized that when a user uninstall the app or clear cache and logs in again the full history is sent. If my user has 1300 messages in the history this will be retrieved in full and my UI is getting stuck. I tried to put the SinchMessageListener initialization in a RXjava observable to execute all that in a new thread and its not working. Still the UI got stuck with every call of onMessageSent, onMessageReceived, onMessageDelivered. Something inside the SDK forces to execute the listener in the UI Thread

What can I do about it? Any work around or idea?

Answer (score 0):

When a Sinch client is created, and "internal" callback handler is created that is bound to the Looper of the current thread. So this issue should be resolved if you creates the Sinch client on a background tread. Though that also means you need to keep that thread around (probably for all app / Android service lifetime), and also dispatching *all* events that will actually trigger any UI update to the main thread

i would filter the messages and dont trigger any ui updates for old messages.

BTW we send the messages for 30 days to a new device.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, another thing, is it possible to receive the history in descending order? to show the user the latest messages while the other are coming. And how do I know how many messages are going to come in that history in advanced?

Comment: Sorry, no. It comes in the order it comes

Comment: then how are your clients doing this? or am I the only one using your service?

Comment: They dont use it as an inbox, you are not alone :D